# Junit how to execute a block of code at the end of theories?

Tags: java, junit

I have set of statements I'd like to execute after all the @DataPoints are executed.

So is there a method that I could execute at the end of running all datapoints.

my code is as follows

```
@RunWith(Theories.class) 
public class Apple{

   @Datapoints
   ----------------
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `@AfterClass` to run after all of the theories have been executed.

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class TheoryTest {
  @DataPoints
  public static Long[] data() {
    return new Long[] { Long.valueOf(3), Long.valueOf(4) };
  }

  @Theory
  public void test1(Long input) {
    System.out.println("test1 input=" + input);
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void afterClass() {
    System.out.println("afterClass");
  }
}
```

produces

```
test1 input=3
test1 input=4
afterClass
```

Comment: What if I wanted to access a non static variable @AfterClass?